# Value doesn't live enough, but can't understand the reason

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, msgpack

Good day!
I'm struggling with a rust program due to a lifetime problem which I can't understand why it happens...It's a tokio thread trying to pass some data to another one using a `mpsc`. The argument is a `&[u8]`, it's a buffer fulfilled by converting a `String` into a MessagePack with `rmp`. I've actually tried to refactor the code a few times, but I can't understand where to move the buffer to avoid to drop it. I can't move it outside from that scope, because it's the only part where it's required the buffer to be sent. This is the actual piece of code:

```
type Router<'a> = Arc<Mutex<
    HashMap<u64, tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<&'a [u8]>
    >>>; // <hash funzione>/<sender>

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Mux<'a> {
    routes: Router<'a>, 
}

#[allow(redundant_semicolons)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub async fn init() -> Result<(), ()> {
    let CONFIG_TOPIC = env::var("CONFIG_TOPIC").unwrap_or("config".into());
    //  Init router
    let routes : Router = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));
    let multiplexer = Mux { routes };
    //  Init client MQTT
    let mut client = client_factory().await;
    let stream = client.get_stream(4096);
    //  Loop richieste
    loop {
        //  Check connessione
        if !client.is_connected() {
            break;
        }
        //  Ricezione
        let opt_message = stream.recv().await.unwrap();
        if opt_message.is_none() {
            println!("M::   None");
            continue;
        }
        let message = opt_message.unwrap();
        let dest_topic = message.topic().to_string();
        //  Estrazione contenuto
        let payload = message.payload(); // it's a slice
        let content = rmp::decode::read_str_from_slice(payload).unwrap().0.to_string();
        //  Lock del multiplexer
        let mut routes = multiplexer.routes.lock().unwrap();
        //
        if dest_topic.eq(&CONFIG_TOPIC) {
            //  Configurazione di un nuovo topic
            //  Iscrizione
            let _sub = client.subscribe(content.clone(), 0 as i32);
            // creazione canale
            let (mSender, iReceiver) = mpsc::channel::<&[u8]>(32);
            //  inserimento
            let key = hash(&content.clone());
            if !routes.contains_key(&key) {
                routes.insert(key, mSender);
            }
            //  spawn invoker
            tokio::spawn(async move{
                invoker::run(iReceiver, dest_topic).await;
            });
            //  stampa stato
            for (k, v) in routes.iter() {
                println!("M::   |{:?}|{:?}|", k, v);
            }
        }else{
            //  Dispatching di una nuova richiesta
            let key = hash(&dest_topic);
            let sender = routes.get(&key).unwrap();
            // preparazione MessagePack
            let mut buffer = Vec::new();
            rmp::encode::write_str(&mut buffer, &content.clone()).unwrap_or_else(|e|{
                ;
            });
            sender.send(&buffer);            
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

//  -- UTILS --
//  Funzione per calcolo di hash
fn hash<T: Hash>(t: &T) -> u64 {
    let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
    t.hash(&mut s);
    s.finish()
}
```

And this is the actual output message from `cargo build`:

```
error[E0597]: `buffer` does not live long enough
  --> src/multiplexer.rs:86:25
   |
86 |             sender.send(&buffer);            
   |                         ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
87 |         }
   |         - `buffer` dropped here while still borrowed
88 |     }
   |     - borrow might be used here, when `routes` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `std::sync::MutexGuard`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

Comment: You're creating `buffer` which is a `Vec` in line 82 inside an `else` block. `buffer` is going to go out of scope at the end of that block in line 87 and will be dropped. When it gets dropped, references to it won't be valid anymore because they'd be pointing to nothing. Because Rust doesn't allow invalid references, you can't send one across a channel.

Comment: `Sender<&'a [u8]>` is almost certainly not what you want. You probably want `Sender<Vec<u8>>`.

Comment: @isaactfa you should post that as solution I guess. op should just pass the owned value of Vec<u8> which is already there.

Comment: Thank you all. Actually, passing the value of Vec<u8> does the trick, I think it could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `buffer` which is a `Vec` in line 82 inside an `else` block. `buffer` is going to go out of scope at the end of that block in line 87 and will be dropped. When it gets dropped, references to it won't be valid anymore because they'd be pointing to nothing. Because Rust doesn't allow invalid references, you can't send it across the channel.

The solution is most likely to change your `Router` type to accept owned `Vec`s instead of slices.

```
type Router = Arc<Mutex<
    HashMap<u64, tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<Vec<u8>>
>>>;
```

And pass your buffer in as such

```
// ...
let mut buffer = Vec::new();
rmp::encode::write_str(&mut buffer, &content.clone()).unwrap_or_else(|e|{
    // ...
});
sender.send(buffer);
// ---------^^^^^^
// pass it by value
// ...
```

If you have another caller where it *does* make sense to pass a reference across the channel, you can use a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) to allow for either:

```
type Router<'a> = Arc<Mutex<
    HashMap<u64, tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender<Cow<'a, [u8]>>
>>>;
```

In `init`:

```
// ...
let mut buffer = Vec::new();
rmp::encode::write_str(&mut buffer, &content.clone()).unwrap_or_else(|e|{
    ;
});
sender.send(Cow::Owned(buffer));
// ...
```

And somewhere else:

```
sender.send(Cow::Borrowed(&some_u8_slice_that_lives_long_enough))
```